# Gravatar Implementation Profile Requests

Tags: php, profile, gravatar

I am trying to retrieve information from Gravatar to my Joomla. I am successful with retrieving my image from gravatar but i am struggling to retrieve other profile information.

```
  $str = file_get_contents('http://www.gravatar.com/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50.php' );
  $profile = unserialize( $str );
  if ( is_array( $profile ) && isset( $profile['entry'] ) )
    echo $profile['entry'][0]['displayName'];

    ?>
```

The following code was on gravatar documentation, and it only outputs my gravtar name. How to obtain other necessary profile information?! I am little bit new to PHP too.

Thank you.

Comment: Information like IM accounts,contact information, email address etc... i can't retrieve them!!

Comment: Those information are not shown to anyone!

Comment: Why is that?! i mean i should be able to access my account and get the information and show it to people isn't it?! So is it not possible to get the other information?! i did only manage to get my gravatar name and the my avatar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I completely misunderstood your question:-D

Values like IMs, email and phone are available if user himself has set them. Have in mind that `$profile['entry'][0]['ims']` is an array  with keys stating from zero to array length minus one.

```
echo $profile['entry'][0]['emails'][0]['value'];
echo $profile['entry'][0]['ims'][0]['value']  ;
echo $profile['entry'][0]['ims'][0]['type']  ;
```

`ims` array is something like this:

```
  ["ims"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(3) "aim"
      ["value"]=>
      string(10) "checkmeout"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(3) "msn"
      ["value"]=>
      string(10) "checkmeout"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(5) "yahoo"
      ["value"]=>
      string(10) "checkmeout"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(3) "icq"
      ["value"]=>
      string(10) "checkmeout"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(5) "gtalk"
      ["value"]=>
      string(10) "checkmeout"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(5) "skype"
      ["value"]=>
      string(10) "checkmeout"
    }
  }
```

Comment: It worked for the email will try making an AIM account :D i did mark it as an answer.